# jQuery plugin with shared variable across all instances?

Tags: jquery

Starting from [this jQuery plugin boilerplate template](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/), how can I define global variables that are shared across *all* instances of the plugin? E.g. if the value changes in one instance, the value of it will be the same in all other instances?

The idea is to write a plugin with drag & drop ability, allowing the user to drag items from one plugin instance to another. To implement this I would like to use a shared variable, e.g. "dragging", which I can then refer to in a mouseover handler in each instance, along with a shared variable "items" containing the DOM nodes of the items currently being dragged.

How can I implement this in a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually solved this, was to add variables to the "class" prototype. See updated boilerplate template below with added comments.

```
// jQuery Plugin Boilerplate
// A boilerplate for jumpstarting jQuery plugins development
// by Stefan Gabos

(function ($) {

    $.pluginName = function (element, options) {

        var defaults = {
            foo: 'bar',
            onFoo: function () { }
        }

        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {}

        var $element = $(element),
            element = element;

        plugin.init = function () {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            // Example event handler
            $element.on('mouseenter', function (e) {

                // Get value of shared variable
                console.log($.pluginName.prototype.mySharedVar);

                // Set value of shared variable
                $.pluginName.prototype.mySharedVar = 'new value';
            });
        }

        plugin.foo_public_method = function () {
        }

        var foo_private_method = function () {
        }

        plugin.init();
    }

    // Shared variable declarations go here
    $.pluginName.prototype.mySharedVar = 'initial value';

    $.fn.pluginName = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('pluginName')) {
                var plugin = new $.pluginName(this, options);
                $(this).data('pluginName', plugin);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```